# yocto do_patch does not work for native

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to write a recipe and it does work well with my patch, but when I add my recipe "`inherit native`" it just simple passes my patch without applying it.

Firstly, I wanted to upgrade one base [recipe](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-oe/recipes-support/gsoap/gsoap_2.8.12.bb) changing its file name to 2.8.33 ( this method generally works for other recipes ). I encountered an error on compile and after I found error, I made a patch and added it to recipe. when I delete native related lines from recipe it successfully compiled. I checked code from work directory I see that my patch applied. But for native compile, I cannot see that my patch applied to extracted code.

gsoap_2.8.33.inc:

```
DESCRIPTION = "The gSOAP toolkit provides a unique SOAP-to-C/C++ language binding \
for the development of SOAP Web Services and clients."
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=f195e609151c013dcfce95528e2d4c63"

SRC_URI = "${SOURCEFORGE_MIRROR}/${BPN}2/${BPN}_${PV}.zip"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "43dade7839252500f7671f8fe6a3739c"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "8534a8bb82ce97544bbb60bf4410ef66f9c328abf62879e499272894019199a4"

inherit autotools


PR = "r1"

S = "${WORKDIR}/gsoap-2.8"


FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir}"
RRECOMMENDS_${PN}-dev = "${PN}-staticdev"

FILES_${PN}-staticdev = "${libdir}"


EXTRA_OECONF_append =" --enable-ipv6 "


EXTRA_OEMAKE = "SOAP=${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/soapcpp2"


PARALLEL_MAKE = ""
```

gsoap-native_2.8.33.bb (does not work and does not patch):

```
inherit native
require gsoap_${PV}.inc

FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "${THISDIR}/:"  


SRC_URI += "file://conf.patch"

PARALLEL_MAKE = ""

DEPENDS = ""
EXTRA_OEMAKE = ""

do_patch_append() {
d.setVar("TEXT", "Hello World")
print d.getVar("TEXT", True)
}

do_install() {
    oe_runmake DESTDIR=${D} BINDIR=${D}${bindir} install
}
```

gsoap_2.8.33.bb (works and does patch when gsoap-native dependency removed):

```
require gsoap_${PV}.inc
DEPENDS = "gsoap-native openssl zlib flex bison"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_append := "${THISDIR}/:"  
SRC_URI += "file://conf.patch" 

do_install_append() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    for lib in libgsoapssl libgsoapssl++ libgsoap libgsoapck++ libgsoap++ libgsoapck
    do
        oe_libinstall -C gsoap $lib ${D}${libdir}
    done
}

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/wsdl2h ${bindir}/soapcpp2"
FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}"
```

my patch:

```
diff --git a/configure b/configure
index a3fade3..8708cad 100755
--- a/configure
+++ b/configure
@@ -6196,7 +6196,7 @@ $as_echo "no" >&6; }
     WSDL2H_EXTRA_FLAGS="-DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_GZIP"
     # an ugly hack to get httpda and smdevp plugins to conditionally
     # compile with wsdl2h when OPENSSL is available
-    WSDL2H_EXTRA_LIBS="${WSDL2H_EXTRA_LIBS} ../plugin/httpda.c ../plugin/smdevp.c ../plugin/threads.c -lssl -lcrypto -lz"
+    #WSDL2H_EXTRA_LIBS="${WSDL2H_EXTRA_LIBS} ../plugin/httpda.c ../plugin/smdevp.c ../plugin/threads.c -lssl -lcrypto -lz"
     SAMPLE_INCLUDES=
     SAMPLE_SSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto -lz"
     WSDL2H_SOAP_CPP_LIB="libgsoapssl++.a"
```

How can I make my recipe 'bitbake'd for cross-compile using my patch?

Comment: Please show the recipe and explain how you've checked that the patch is not applied.

Comment: @jku I made some changes on the question

Comment: Sorry but there's still nothing here to work on... Why not show the recipe that doesn't work instead of linking to the one that apparently works?

Comment: @jku I made some changes on the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still not explaining what exactly fails and how you've checked that... I tested your gsoap-native recipe and after removing the broken do_patch_append() function it patches fine: after `bitbake -c patch gsoap-native` I can see the patched source in the gsoap-native work directory.

Some notes:

- You're patching a file that will get regenerated during do_configure (autotools class will run `autoreconf`) -- maybe this is why you think the patching is not happening. Modify configure.ac instead.
- There should be no need to separate the native and target recipes: the original recipe in meta-openembedded already supports building both gsoap and gsoap-native. If you need to add a patch to make a newer version work then do that, don't start writing new recipes.